# "Руки не доходят"

Tags: фразеология

Вот интересно, когда хотят сказать, что человек никак не соберется что-то сделать, то говорят, что у него "руки не доходят". Но почему руки — и ходят?))

Answer (score 3):

Это разговорный фразеологизм, слово "доходят" употреблено в переносном значении "останавливаться на ком-либо, чем-либо, перебирая, перечисляя кого-либо, что-либо по порядку, в определенной последовательности". Дойти может дело, разговор. Например:"Сначала сделали ..., потом ..., потом дошли до крыши". Вот и руки сначала делают это, потом другое, потом дойдут и ещё до  чего-то, а до чего-то так и не дойдут, времени не хватит или желания хозяина.

Answer (score 0):

Считайте, что здесь "не доходят" употреблено в смысле "не дотягиваются". По причине их постоянной занятости чем-то другим. 
Не совсем точно, но что-то близкое.